# Computational complexity for casting int to unsigned vs complexity for comparing values

Tags: c++, c, casting

I just wanted to know which operation is faster in C/C++, as well as what the computational complexity for a type cast is.

Typecasting x to an unsigned integer like so:

```
(unsigned int) x
```

or

Performing a comparison between x and a constant:

```
x<0
```

edit: computational complexity as in which process requires the least amount of bit operations on a low level aspect of the hardware in order to successfully carry out the instruction.

**edit #2:** So to give some context what I'm specifically trying to do is seeing if reducing

```
if( x < 0)
```

into

```
if((((unsigned int)x)>>(((sizeof(int))<<3)-1)))
```

would be more efficient or not if done over 100,000,000 times, with large quantities for x, above/below (+/-)50,000,000

Comment: This is architecture-dependent.  And this question smells of premature optimization.  Give a real life example, and specify target architecture.

Comment: The notion of "computational complexity" only makes sense when you have input whose size can grow, at least theoretically, to infinity.

Comment: Computational complexity doesn't generally make sense for a question like this. Computational complexity normally deals with the behavior as the number of input elements approaches infinity, but in this case there's only one element to consider. If you're dealing with a single item of unbounded size (e.g., factoring a huge number) it can sort of make sense. Assuming `x` is an unbounded integer type, the cast will still generally be constant complexity. In this case, the comparison probably will be as well, but something like `x>y` might not be.

Comment: By computational complexity I was headed towards what process has the least number of bit operations that must be done in order to complete the instruction

Comment: It totally depends on what _context_ this is used under, and what architecture you are compiling against.

Comment: @ILoveAnime the CPU doesn't process the data for the integer comparison bit-by-bit: it does them all in parallel.  And the cast doesn't even involve bit processing, in and of itself.

Comment: I think the Lisp tag is needed here too

Comment: @M.M lol sorry for all the parenthesis

Comment: 99.99% chance this is a micro-optimization that is absolutely not worth worrying about. If you absolutely -must- check, you're going to have to look at the generated assembly code for both, and then look at instruction latency/throughputs (see [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), if it's x86-based) at a minimum, though.

Comment: I think that you want `if((((unsigned int)x)>(((sizeof(int))<<3)-1)))` . This introduces a `>` operator instead of a `<` operator.

Comment: @Rishi no the bitshift operation was intentional

Comment: +1 @JerryCoffin 's comment.  You are using basic types (and only one).  The number of bits is fixed (whatever that number may be for your architecture).  Let the compiler figure out how to do it in the fewest or most efficient instructions.  Compilers are more clever than you might give them credit for.

Comment: @Yuushi Thank you I will definitely take a look at the paper you linked.

Comment: That last one is horribly inefficient because it takes far too long for a reader to parse all those parentheses to figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(unsigned int) x` is - for the near-universal 2's complement notation - a compile time operation: you're telling the compiler to treat the content of `x` as an `unsigned` value, which doesn't require any runtime machine-code instructions in and of itself, but may change the machine code instructions it emits to support the usage made of the `unsigned` value, or even cause dead-code elimination optimisations, for example the following could be eliminated completely after the cast:

```
if ((unsigned int)my_unsigned_int >= 0)
```

The relevant C++ Standard quote (my boldfacing):

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ *Note*: In a **two’s
>   complement** representation, **this conversion is conceptual** and there is **no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation)**. —end note ]

There could be an actual bitwise change requiring an operation on some bizarre hardware using 1's complement or sign/magnitude representations.  (Thanks Yuushi for highlighting this in comments).

That contrasts with `x < 0`, which - for a signed `x` about which the compiler has no special knowledge, does require a CPU/machine-code instruction to evaluate (if the result is used) and corresponding runtime.  That comparison instruction tends to take 1 "cycle" on even older CPUs, but do keep in mind that modern CPU pipelines can execute many such instruction in parallel during a single cycle.

> `if( x < 0)` vs `if((((unsigned int)x)>>(((sizeof(int))<<3)-1)))` - faster?

The first will always be at least as fast as the second.  A comparison to zero is a bread-and-butter operation for the CPU, and the C++ compiler's certain to use an efficient opcode (machine code instruction) for it: you're wasting your time trying to improve on that.

Comment: This is true for anything that uses two's complement representation (just about everything these days) - it might not be true for some bizzaro architecture that uses sign/magnitude (for example).

Comment: @Yuushi huh? `unsigned int` is always >= 0 regardless of representation of signed values

Comment: @M.M Not the `if` check, but the actual cast itself - just like `(float) x` would actually require most (all?) architectures to produce an actual instruction to modify the bit pattern (e.g. `cvtsi2ss` on x86).

Comment: @Yuushi Ah, I see what you are saying now.  It depends what is then done with the result of the cast though. For example the compiler really does not have to generate any instructions for TonyD's code sample

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual edited question, it is unlikely to be faster. In the best case, if `x` is known at compile time, the compiler will be able to optimize out the branch completely in both cases.

If `x` is a run-time value, then the first will produce a single test instruction. The second will likely produce a shift-right immediate followed by a test instruction.

Comment: x is a runtime variable, but why would the second produce an additional compare instruction?

Comment: @ILoveAnime Sorry, test instruction, not compare. In fact, gcc using `-O2` generates almost exactly the same code for both, so it's smart enough to optimize out the right-shift.

Comment: wow, that's actually pretty amazing that it can optimize the right shift out.

Answer (score 0):

The monster `if((((unsigned int)x)>>(((sizeof(int))<<3)-1)))` will be slower than the straight forward `if(x < 0)`: Both versions need to compare a value against zero, but your monster adds a shift before the comparison can take place.